# Table of contents exclusive to a particular section or chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a document with a short main-body but a huge appendix. The body just has a couple of short sections, so I wouldnt like to have any Table of Contents for them. The Appendix on the other hand contains about 50 pages of a lot of different programs used to generate the results. Without a TOC it is a navigational mess. I want a TOC only for the Appendix which starts at the page the appendix starts.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Main Body}
So here is what I found out...

\appendix
\tableofcontents

In case you wish to reproduce these fantastic results here is the code

\chapter*{Appendix A} Program A
\chapter*{Appendix B} Program B
\chapter*{Appendix C} Program C
\chapter*{Appendix D} Program D
% and so on...

\end{document}
```

I tried the above and it wasnt working, though I havent found a workaround for it over the itnernet.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `tocdepth` counter to -2 at the beginning, for not displaying chapters in the table of contents, and change the value of `tocdepth` to 0 or higher right before the appendix chapters. So you can use non-starred chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main Body}
So here is what I found out...

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\tableofcontents

In case you wish to reproduce these fantastic results here is the code

\chapter{Appendix A} Program A
\chapter{Appendix B} Program B
\chapter{Appendix C} Program C
\chapter{Appendix D} Program D
% and so on...

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`tocvsec2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) package for adjusting the numbering depth:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\settocdepth{part}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main Body}
So here is what I found out...

\appendix
\settocdepth{section}
\tableofcontents
In case you wish to reproduce these fantastic results here is the code

\chapter{Appendix A} Program A
\chapter{Appendix B} Program B
\chapter{Appendix C} Program C
\chapter{Appendix D} Program D
% and so on...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The starred `chapter` commands doesn't appear in the TOC. If you use the unstarred version in the appendix, but the starred version in the main body, your example will work, I guess.

If you want the first appendix to start immediately below the TOC, the hack I added to the example will do that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Main Body}
So here is what I found out...

\appendix
\tableofcontents

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\chapter{Appendix A}
\endgroup
\chapter{Appendix B} Program B
\chapter{Appendix C} Program C
\chapter{Appendix D} Program D
% and so on...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{book}
\def\Chapter#1{\chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Main Body}
So here is what I found out...

\appendix
\tableofcontents

In case you wish to reproduce these fantastic results here is the code

\Chapter{Appendix A} Program A
\Chapter{Appendix B} Program B
\Chapter{Appendix C} Program C
\Chapter{Appendix D} Program D
% and so on...

\end{document}
```